# What is the expected Ether issuance schedule after transition to PoS?

Tags: ether

Is there anywhere I can read the latest Ether issuance schedule plan? I understand what it is now (5 eth / block plus uncle rewards), but what will it be after proof of stake? I've read conflicting things about that and am confused.